# How to delete all lines in a command script without provoking error?

Tags: command-line

I'm trying to write a Vim command script (a file containing Ex commands) that removes all existing lines in a file (and then read in some new text, and do some further editing operations).  I use the command `% delete _` which generates the error "E749: empty buffer" and eventually when Vim terminates produces exit code 1.

I tried prefixing the command with `:silent!` and I also tried putting it in a `:try ... :catch ... :endtry` segment, but neither of those made any difference.

EDIT: Here's a simple example:

```
new
append
hello world
.
%delete_
```

I put that into a file called "sc" and run it with `vim -es <sc` (with or without `-V1`).

Comment: E749 takes me to `:print` in the help. Running `:new | %delete _` I did not get any errors. Can you [edit] with exact steps to reproduce?

Comment: Thanks, @D.BenKnoble.  Added an example.  Also, yes, I noticed that help took me to `:print`, but I couldn't understand why (it doesn't seem to have anything to do with printing).

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Does it help if you add a space in between the `delete` and the `_`? I think that might be the problem.

Comment: @filbranden No, adding a space doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: Yes I can reproduce the issue with your instructions. Interesting!

Comment: No error at all in 9.0.1276.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error from running in [Ex-mode](https://vimhelp.org/intro.txt.html#Ex-mode), which in your case you're getting through passing Vim the [`-e`](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#-e) command-line argument, but you could equally get there by running the `ex` command directly (instead of `vim`), or using the [`Q`](https://vimhelp.org/intro.txt.html#Q) Normal-mode command to enter Ex-mode.

The error message is coming from [this line in `do_exmode()`, which implements the Ex-mode loop](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.4937/src/ex_docmd.c#L524). After running an Ex command, it will perform some checks and raise error `E749` if the buffer is empty.

Digging into history of this code, it seems this behavior was introduced in Vim version 7.0051, from February 2005, so it's been this way for a long time.

Looking at the code around that line, there's another error that might be raised there, which is `E501: At end-of-file`, which is raised if you press enter on the Ex prompt (i.e. `:<CR>`) while you're at the last line of the buffer. Pressing enter on the Ex prompt will advance you to the next line. In light of that behavior, it makes sense that doing so at the end of the buffer will raise an error.

An empty buffer is, in a sense, a corner case of that, since technically you're at or past the last line of the buffer, even though you're also at the first and only line. That probably justifies raising an error in that situation, and the authors probably picked `E749: empty buffer` as it's more descriptive than the `E501` error.

There doesn't seem to be a workaround for this issue. Maybe you can avoid using Ex-mode? Maybe you can avoid the situation where the buffer gets completely empty? But indeed `:silent!` or `:try` won't help, because the error is not really coming from the `:delete` command, but from the Ex-mode loop, after the command has emptied the buffer.

Comment: So, Ex raises an error when any command leaves the buffer empty? That sounds odd…

Comment: Seems to be corrected, but I can't find from what version.

Comment: @gildux Which version are you testing? I just checked Vim 9.0.981 and I can still reproduce the behavior. Are you testing this on Vim or Neovim?

Comment: Vim 9.0 (2022 June 28) including patches 1-639. I've launched `ex` directly, typed `new<CR>` without error, typed `append<CR>` then `hello world<CR>.<CR>` without error, typed `%delete_<CR>` and had a new-line as output. To be sure, I tried `%list<CR>` and it said `E749: Empty buffer` as expected. Last, I typed `quit<CR>`  and it said `E37: No write since last change (add ! to override)` of course. But `q!<CR>` showed in it's place `[e]  <empty buffer>` hmm… Another `q!<CR>` let me exit however. https://imgur.com/a/aoTse6E